# Casting/dereferencing char pointers to a double array

Tags: c++, pointers

Is there anything wrong with the casting a double pointer to a char pointer?  Goal in the following code is to change the 1 element in three different ways.

```
double   vec1[100];
double   *vp = vec1;
char     *yp = (char*) vp;
vp++;
vec1[1] = 19.0;
*vp = 12.0;
*((double*) (yp + (1*sizeof (vec1[0])))) = 34.0;
```

Comment: What happened when you ran it?

Comment: How is this code any different from `double vec1[100]; vec1[1] = 34.0;`?

Comment: OP says the goal is to manipulate the same element in multiple ways

Comment: **Why** do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casts of this type fall into the category of "OK if you know what you're doing but dangerous if you don't".

For example, in this case you already know the pointer value of "yp" (it was pointing to a `double`) so it is technically safe to increase its value by the size of a `double` and re-cast back to a `double*`.

A counter-example: suppose you *didn't* know where the `char*` came from...say, it was given to you as a function parameter.  Now, your cast would be a big problem: since `char*` is technically 1-byte-aligned and a `double` is usually 8-byte-aligned, you can't be sure if you were given an 8-byte-aligned address.  If it's aligned, your arithmetic would produce a valid `double*`; if not, it would crash when dereferenced.

This is just one example of how casts can go wrong.  What you're doing (at first glance) looks like it will work but in general you really have to pay attention when you cast things.

Comment: Note that the alignment is not the only thing that makes a double valid. Many bit patterns do not represent valid doubles... and that could also generate an interrupt depending on your FPU settings.

Comment: That's true but in this case he is clearly assigning valid floating-point numbers through each pointer.

Answer (score 0):

With newer INTEL processors the main problem you can run into is alignment. Say you were to write something like this:

```
*((double*) (yp + 4)) = 34.0;
```

Then you are likely to have a runtime error because a double should be aligned on 8 bytes. This was also true on processors such as 68k, or MIPS.

This is similar to having a structure and doing casts on that structure. You are not unlikely to break things.

In most cases, if you can avoid such, your code will be a lot stronger. Personally, I do not even use such casts when reading a file. Instead, I get the data from the file and put it in a structure as required. Say I read 4 bytes in a buffer to convert to an integer, I'd write something like this:

```
unsigned char buf[4];
...
fread(buf, 1, 4, f);
my_struct.integer = buf[0] | (buf[1] << 8) | (buf[2] << 16) | (buf[3] << 24);
```

Now I did not do an ugly cast and I could control the endianess of the integer in the file whatever the endian of the processor you are running with.

Comment: This doesn’t correspond to OP’s code – OP is using the `sizeof` the individual elements so there are no conceivable alignment problems.

Comment: Why would you need to use a `char*` pointer if you had the `vec1` array right at hand? I find it strange that he used `sizeof(vec1[0])` instead of `sizeof(double)` but did not find it relevant to my answer.

Comment: Well, the *purpose* of this code is shrouded in mystery, of course. I was just pointing out that, as written by OP, it’s safe. Using `sizeof(vec1[0])` is recommended because it means that you’re not repeating the data type, and thus don’t risk a type (size) mismatch once you change the declaration type and forget to change the type at other sites of usage.

Comment: Purpose of this code is an exercise.  Was not sure if I was missing the point to the question.